# MatLab Plotting Function Matrix Dimension Error

Tags: matlab

I have a simple function written

```
function[] = myfun(p,q)
fminbnd(@(x)myfun1(q,p,b),0,1)
```

where myfun1's output is from the function quad.

How do I plot myfun? I've tried fplot(@(x)myfun(1,x),0,1) but this gives me a matrix dimensions must agree error...

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not contain enough information to identify exactly where the problem lies, but one issue is certainly that `myfun` does not return any output. What should `fplot` plot, if there is nothing returned by the function?

Try

```
function out = myfun(p,q)
%# you may want to define b here
out = fminbnd(@(x)myfun1(q,p,b),0,1);
```

If that doesn't fix the issue, turn on the debugging mode by typing `dbstop if error` at the command line. This will show where exactly the error occurs, and allow you to inspect the variables for correct shape.